# Centering an oversized Div element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I've got Div element which is 1680px wide, like this:

```
|                   |
```

Say, the actual screen/browser canvas resolution is 800px wide:

```
+      +
```

Now, how do I center the Div (and hide the rest) using jQuery so that the rest of the 1680px goes hidden, like this:

```
|     +      +      |
 ^^^^^        ^^^^^^

^ = clipped from the Div.
```

In other words, I want the Div the be shown within those two + range and hide the rest. If the actual screen resolution is bigger that 1680px, the the Div should be centered normally without any clipping.

I'm not sure if I was able to explain this dilemma perfectly, so ask away if something is unclear. This has been driven me mad already...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CSS` only:

http://jsfiddle.net/rQfvs/

The key part being:

```
#bigdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 1680px;
    margin-left: -840px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Note that you do not necessarily need the `container` div, either.  You can simply put the `bigdiv` in the main body.  I would set the body's overflow to hidden as well in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/rQfvs/3/

Comment: Very good. I didn't think that this is possible with just CSS.

Comment: It is as long as you know the width of your div.

Comment: From what I can see, you only have to set the margin-left property to the value width/2... you can do that via JavaScript even if the width is not hard-coded into CSS. But those scenarios should be rare. Fixed width layouts always have a CSS width, so you just have to place the margin-left property beneath it and make sure that it has the correct value.